# How can I improve my game performance on Wine?

Tags: ati, wine, games

After downloading Ubuntu 14.10, I decided to download Steam using wine so I could play a couple of new games that I brought (Morrowind, Oblivion and Skyrim). The installations were successful, however all three games were running incredibly slow. I previously had Windows 8.1 and the games ran smoothly with only small amount of fps drop here and there during game play. Everything from cut scenes to loading screens, menus and actual game play are horrendously slow and I've never had this issue before considering I'm using a mid-range laptop. Whilst it would probably be best going on to winehq forums to discuss this matter, I thought I would come to askubuntu to see if anyone here would be able to answer my question. My processor is an AMD E1-6010 APU with AMD Radeon R2 Graphics × 2 and my graphics are Gallium 0.4 on AMD MULLINS. I am currently using an open source driver (AMD/ATI Display Wrapper). Is this a matter of installing the proprietary driver or is there another alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open source drivers don't use the hardware to its fullest capacity, therefore your games are going to run slower. You should use the proprietary drivers for your GPU. They're maintained by AMD themselves; only they can write a driver that uses the GPU to its fullest potential.

Additionally, Wine provides rather rough compatibility for Windows applications. Considering the nature of Wine, your performance could take a hit.